# OpenSSL / AES/GCM: Optimal way to encrypt data with multiple IVs

Tags: openssl, aes

I am encrypting a stream of data using OpenSSL C API and AES/GCM with 16-byte ivs. The stream is split into several chunks that need to be encrypted with the same key but different ivs. So far I have the following flow (pseudo code):

```
for all data chunks:
    iv = newIv()
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL)
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv))

    EVP_EncryptUpdate
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG...

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free
```

I am looking into improving performance by reusing objects, ideally the following way:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL)
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 16, NULL))

for all data chunks:
    iv = newIv()
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv))

    EVP_EncryptUpdate
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG...

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free
```

Are there any concerns with the approach? How about also doing that for decryption?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It is C, i edited the post.

Comment: This doesn't even look close to C more like a mix of Ruby and Python.

Comment: this is pseudo code showing how the C functions are called

Comment: So have you tried this? What's the issue? And apart from the key schedule of AES, what do you expect to gain by reusing the objects? Creating an new object / context will be quite fast; allocating the memory will probably take "the most" time.

Comment: It actually depends on the data chunks size. If they are small (<1kB for example), the time is dominated by context creation/initialization so reusing the context is a big performance boost (I have no control on the data chunk size in my application). I tried it and it seems to work, but the openssl documentation is not clear about recommending to do that, so I would like to know if there are any concern with the approach.